# Retina Images on CSS3 pseudo elements

Tags: css, responsive-design, retina-display, pseudo-element

I have always successfully used the retina image technique described by [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/) using background-size and media queries.

However I just discovered a case where this technique doesn't seems to work : styling CSS3 pseudo elements.

```
<p>test</p>

p:before {
  content: url('http://file.rspreprod.fr/BNP/Maps/img/web/ic_pin_big@2x.png');
  background-size: 15px 25px;
  width:15px;
  height:25px;
}
```

Check this JS Fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/t29xzxmw/2/

On iPhone and Android, the image is not crystal clear as it should be. 
Do you know a solution to apply retina images to CSS3 pseudo elements ?

Comment: Is the `p:before` rule contained within an appropriate media query?

Comment: In my code yes, in the example I removed the media query for simplicity.

Comment: This isn't going to work. It's not accepting the background size. It won't because it's not a background image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t29xzxmw/4/

Comment: o_O why didn't I see this... thanks. However the problem remains : how can we use CSS3 pseudo elements with retina displays?

Comment: @Christina well done! you can put this as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `background` instead of `content:""`

```
p:before {
  content:"";
  background:url('http://file.rspreprod.fr/BNP/Maps/img/web/ic_pin_big@2x.png');
  background-size: 15px 25px;
  width:15px;
  height:25px;
}
```